Is the GIT quotient of an affine scheme by an algebraic group also a quotient of the corresponding Zariski sheaves?
Let $X=Spec(A)$ be an affine scheme and $G=Spec(H)$ be a reduced algebraic group action on X (over a field of characteristic 0).
Affine GIT tells us that the quotient in the category of Schemes exists and it is given by $X//G:= Spec A^G$. (Of course, this is the categorical quotient, not necessarily the geometric quotient).
On the other hand, Schemes can be characterized as sheaves over the big Zariski site \underline{Sch}_{Zar} that admit an affine Zariski cover. In this setting, it is natural to take the quotient $X/G$ of the representable sheaf $h_X$ by the representable group sheaf $h_G$. It is given by the sheafification of the presheaf
$$\underline{Sch} \longrightarrow \underline{Sets}: T \longmapsto X(T)/G(T)$$
My question is what the relation is between the GIT quotient $X//G$ and the sheaf quotient $X/G$? Is the categorical quotient in the category schemes the same as the quotient in the category of Zariski sheaves $Sh(\underline{Sch}_{Zar},\underline{Sets})$?

They are not equal. What happens if you think about the cokernel of $\mathbb{G}{m,\mathbb{Q}}\to\mathbb{G}{m,\mathbb{Q}}$ given by the squaring map?

Do you perhaps mean the fppf topology? That is more reasonable.

@AlexYoucis I have very little intuition on what to expect here I have to say. Do you mean the quotient as fppf-sheaves? For context: I am working on an example where the GIT quotient is simply a point, and I want to motivate why the quotient sheaves (Zariski, étale, or fppf) are not of interest either, but the quotient stack which is algebraic, does work well.

This feels a bit misguided. You know that the GIT quotient is the coarse space of the associated stack quotient, right? So it has obvious pros and cons, e.g., it has the right geometric points and is simpler (it’s a scheme), but it doesn’t capture the correct behavior in non-trivial families.

@AlexYoucis I thought that If the GIT quotient is not a geometric quotient, it is not a coarse space of the quotient stack, and so it doesnt neatly catch all geometric points (e.g. representing non closed orbits). My question probably is misguided indeed: I aim to know what does not work with the quotient sheaves, perhaps i shouldn't drag the GIT quotient in the picture.
